# ¿Cómo modificar el box del servicio de indicaciones de Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps, google-api

Estoy trabajando en una web para remis/taxi con la API de Google Maps, me guie de la página de la API "Place Autocomplete and Directions", y lo que necesito hacer es que a través de un formulario se ingrese datos de la persona y dos direcciones "A" y "B", las cuales serian para trazar una ruta del punto "A" al "B", calcular la distancia y me trace el recorrido en un mapa. Hasta ahora logre que me muestre en el mapa el recorrido, pero por mas que cambio la ubicación del formulario de ingreso de datos siempre termina apareciendo dentro del mapa y desde ahí buscar, pero no es lo que quiero. Necesito ingresar por formulario y que se actualice el mapa con el recorrido correcto solo en Automóvil. Me darían una mano?[image: Asi es como esta mi pagina ahora, pero en el mapa abajo es donde quiero modificar para que ingrese por la parte del formulario de arriba]  Así es como esta mi pagina ahora, pero en el mapa que se ve en parte de abajo de la imagen es donde quiero modificar para que ingrese por la parte del formulario de arriba.

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: { lat: -27.492045640978436, lng:-58.82678797211838 },
    zoom: 16,
  });
  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

class AutocompleteDirectionsHandler {
  constructor(map) {
    this.map = map;
    //this.originPlaceId = "";
    //this.destinationPlaceId = "";
    this.travelMode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    const originInput = document.getElementById("origin-input");
    const destinationInput = document.getElementById("destination-input");
    const modeSelector = document.getElementById("mode-selector");
    const originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
    // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
    originAutocomplete.setFields(["place_id"]);
    const destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
    // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
    destinationAutocomplete.setFields(["place_id"]);
    this.setupClickListener(
      "changemode-walking",
      google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
    );
    this.setupClickListener(
      "changemode-transit",
      google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
    );
    this.setupClickListener(
      "changemode-driving",
      google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    );
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, "ORIG");
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, "DEST");
    
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
  }
  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  setupClickListener(id, mode) {
    const radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.travelMode = mode;
      this.route();
    });
  }
  setupPlaceChangedListener(autocomplete, mode) {
    autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      if (!place.place_id) {
        window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
        return;
      }

      if (mode === "ORIG") {
        this.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        this.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      }
      this.route();
    });
  }
  route() {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
    }
    const me = this;
    this.directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: { placeId: this.originPlaceId },
        destination: { placeId: this.destinationPlaceId },
        travelMode: this.travelMode,
      },
      (response, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}


.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}

#origin-input:focus,
#destination-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="Javier Valdivia" content="">
    <meta name="generator" content="">
    <title>Carniceria</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/">
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/go1.css" />-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="./js/go1.js"></script>
    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="navbar-inicio.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    
<header>
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CADETERIA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="pedir.html">Pedir</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <!--<input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button  class="btn btn-success"  href="login.html">Login</button>-->
          <a href="login.html" class="btn btn-success">Ingresar</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

    <!-- Contenedor del Formulario de solicitar remis -->
<main class="flex-shrink-1">
    <div class="container container-sm ">
        <div class="container container-sm ">
            <form class= "row mb-4 g-3 col-8 mx-auto">
                    <h2>Remis</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <!-- Nombre Y apellido del cliente -->
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div  class="form-group">
                        
                        <button class="btn btn-pocision btn-primary">Mi Posicion</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        
                    </div>
                    <!-- este Boton solicita el remis -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success button" class="form-control">Solicitar Remis</button>
                    </div>
            </form>

            

            <!-- buscador direcciones internet -->
            
            <form class= "row mb-4 g-3 col-8 mx-auto">
                <div class="form-group input-group ">
                    <!--<input type="text" id="search_location" class="form-control" placeholder="Search location">-->
                    <input id="origin-input"
                            class="controls"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Desde formulario btn"/>

                            <input
                            id="destination-input"
                            class="controls"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Hasta formulario btn"
                          />

                            <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
                                <input
                                  type="radio"
                                  name="type"
                                  id="changemode-walking"
                                  checked="checked"
                                />
                                <label for="changemode-walking">Caminar</label>

                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit" />
                                <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

                                <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving" />
                                <label for="changemode-driving">Auto</label>
                            </div>-->
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                            calcular ruta
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        
            
                    <style>
                        .google-maps {
                            position: relative;
                            padding-bottom: 75%;
                            height: 0;
                            overflow: inherit;
                        }
                        .google-maps iframe {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: 0;
                            width: 100% !important;
                            height: 100% !important;
                        }
                    </style>
                    
        </div>
    </div>

  <!-- Contenedor del mapa -->
  <style>
    #map{
        height: 30rem;
    }
</style>
    <div>
        <div>
                  <div>
                  
                  <input
                    id="origin-input"
                    class="controls"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Desde"
                  />

                  <input
                    id="destination-input"
                    class="controls"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Hasta"
                  />
              </div>

                      
        </div>
                 
                 <!--<div id="map" class="col-8 "></div>-->
                    
                        <div class="shadow" id="map">
                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4319.152096329275!2d-58.78784059708397!3d-27.4649792738881!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94456b1ea8ed01d1%3A0x1d4fbbcdfeb75daa!2sMaxikiosco%20Corrientes!5e1!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1618977226734!5m2!1ses!2sar" width="1108px" height="480px" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                        </div>     
    </div>



    
</main>
    
    

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDm6pawnfRP1K1ctjZ4pr6m060RqtOg8Tw&&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly" type="text/javascript"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```